# Program/Method Flow with Threads

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, user-interface, uialertview

I have a UIAlertView that initiates an update process.
The UIAlertView asks the user whether they'd like to update or not.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([connection isReachable]){
        [updateLabel setText:@"Connection Active. Checking Update Status"];
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Update Available" message:@"Your File Database is Out of Date. Would you like to Update?\nNote: Updates can take a long time depending on the required files." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Later" otherButtonTitles:@"Update Now", nil] show];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [self updateFiles:[UpdateManager getUpdateFiles]];
    }
}
```

The above code runs fine, however, within my updateFiles: method, I require some UI adjustments.

```
- (void)updateFiles:(NSArray *)filesList {
    for (NSDictionary *file in filesList) {
        [updateLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading File: %@", [file objectForKey:@"Name"]]];
        [UpdateManager updateFile:[file objectForKey:@"File Path"]];
    }
    [updateIndicator stopAnimating];
    [updateLabel setText:@"Update Completed"];
}
```

The UIAlertView doesn't dismiss until after the for statement in the updateFiles method is run.

I can't get the updateLabel to display the files it's currently downloading, though at the end of the update process, we do get a 'Update Completed' in the label.

Can anybody help?

**UPDATE**

I'm starting to suspect this is more of a process that's being delayed by some heavy synchronous processes. For example, my `[UpdateManager getUpdateFiles]` method is heavy and involves getting resources from the web. Likewise with my `[UpdateManager updateFile:[file objectForKey:@"File Path"]];` method.

Is there any way I can force the UI updates to take priority over these methods?

I'm just trying to give the user some feedback on what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I couldn't update the UI and process some heavy methods on the same thread.
Since I can only update the UI on the main thread, I had to do some re-organising to ensure the processes were on a background thread, but then promote the UI changes to the main.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateFiles:) withObject:[UpdateManager getUpdateFiles]];
    }
}

- (void)updateFiles:(NSArray *)filesList {
    for (NSDictionary *file in filesList) {
        [updateLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading File: %@", [file objectForKey:@"Name"]]];
        [UpdateManager updateFile:[file objectForKey:@"File Path"]];
    }
    [updateIndicator stopAnimating];
    [updateLabel setText:@"Update Completed"];
}
```

So, I send `updateFiles:` to the background and promote `setText:` and any other UI changes to the Main Thread.